# Kommas vor „aber/wie“ in „sowohl …(,) aber/wie auch …“?

Tags: comma

Betrachten wir folgende Beispiele:

> Und das wäre sowohl ich als Autor, aber auch Sie als Leser, obwohl wir in diesem Fall nicht auf der Insel sind.

(Quelle: http://docplayer.org/56711208-Der-jovialismus-oder-die-freiheit-nein-zu-sagen.html.)

> Die Farbe Orange enthält sowohl rot wie auch gelb.

(Quelle: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sowohl_%E2%80%A6_wie_auch.)

Stimmen die Beispiele? Wie ist das Vorhandensein bzw. die Abwesenheit der Kommas in diesen Fällen geregelt und warum?

Comment: Unabhängig von der Frage des Kommas tut mir zumindest der zweite Beispielsatz ziemlich weh. Da müsste *als auch* stehen, nicht *wie auch*. Treibt die Sprachvergewaltigung aus *A ist größer wie B* hier in neuen bereichen ihr Unwesen? Im ersten Beispiel kann man das *sowohl (...) **aber** auch* stehenlassen, wenn das *sowohl* im Sinne von *in erster Linie* gemeint ist.

Comment: Dass Du das nicht selbst verbrochen, sondern nur wörtlich zitiert hast, war mir schon klar - andernfalls hätte ich es vermutlich noch "heftiger" formuliert ;-)

Comment: *Rot* und *Gelb* müssen als Farbsubstantive großgeschrieben werden.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily,  "A, aber auch/nicht B" takes a comma, while "sowohl X als auch Y" doesn't. Your first example is a mix-up between both forms and doesn't really have a "standard" behaviour. I suppose most people would put the comma if pressed, since there is a rather strong (but not universal!) regularity of having a comma directly in front of an "aber" used as a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

Ich beginne mit dem zweiten Beispielsatz:

> Die Farbe Orange enthält sowohl rot wie auch gelb.

Richtigerweise steht hier kein Komma, denn gemäß § 72 des [Amtlichen Regelwerks 2018](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201) gilt:

> **§ 72** Sind die gleichrangigen Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter durch *und, oder, beziehungsweise/bzw., sowie (= und), wie (= und), entweder … oder, nicht … noch, sowohl … als (auch), sowohl … wie (auch)* oder durch *weder … noch* verbunden, so setzt man kein Komma.

Beim ersten Beispielsatz ist die Situation eine andere:

> Und das wäre sowohl ich als Autor, aber auch Sie als Leser, obwohl wir in diesem Fall nicht auf der Insel sind.

Hier sind die Wortgruppen durch die entgegenstellende Konjunktion *aber* verbunden, weshalb gemäß Ergänzung E2 zu §72 richtigerweise ein Komma vor *aber* stehen muss:

> **E2:** Bei entgegenstellenden Konjunktionen wie *aber, doch, jedoch, sondern* steht nach der Grundregel (§ 71) ein Komma, wenn sie zwischen gleichrangigen Wörtern oder Wortgruppen stehen […]